# Undefined reference SHA_Update . OpenSSL in C

Tags: c, hash, reference, openssl, undefined

I am learning OpenSSL to obtain the hash of a file in C. When I compile the code, i get this undefined reference error in SHA_Update and SHA_Final

Here is the code:

```
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define BUFF_SIZE 256

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   int fd;
   char buff[BUFF_SIZE];
   int i = 0;

   SHA_CTX sha_ctx;
   unsigned char sha_hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];

   SHA1_Init(&sha_ctx);

   fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY, 0);
   do {
      i = read(fd, buff, i);
      SHA_Update(&sha_ctx, buff, i);
   } while(i > 0);
   close(fd);

   SHA_Final(sha_hash, &sha_ctx);

   printf("\n Hash of the file: %s \n\n", argv[1]);
   for(i = 0; i < SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH; ++i) {
      printf("%x", sha_hash[i]);
   }
   printf("\n\n");
   return 0;
}
```

To compile I used:

```
gcc -g hash.c -lcrypto
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function names are: `SHA1_Update` and `SHA1_Final` (You had `SHA_Update` and `SHA_Final`, see the missing 1?)